# Sampling/Asymptotic Distribution of Estimated Coefficients of Logistic Regression

Tags: logistic, maximum-likelihood, asymptotics, estimators, sampling-distribution

If I understand correctly, in a logistic regression, we have that $Y_i \mid X \sim Bern(S(X\beta))$ where $S(x)$ is the sigmoid function.

Suppose we estimate $\beta$ using MLE and get $\hat \beta$. Now, from what I found online, $\hat\beta$ doesn't have a closed-form solution and is estimated by numerically solving $\partial \ell/\partial\beta = 0$ where $\ell(X\beta; \mathbf y)$ is the log-likelihood function (is this correct?).

Given that we don't even have a closed-form solution for this estimator, do we know the sampling distribution of $\hat\beta?$

How do we get asymptotic distribution for $\hat\beta$ (somewhere I think CLT will be used but how)?

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27322/are-logistic-regression-coefficient-estimates-biased-when-the-predictor-has-larg  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/303180/standard-error-of-the-estimate-in-logistic-regression  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/258788/normally-distributed-estimated-parameters-in-logistic-regression  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85682/how-does-maximum-likelihood-estimation-have-an-approximate-normal-distribution

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: thanks a lot for these references. The second link seem to answer my question (will look more into in detail as I have some doubts there). Fourth is also very interesting, as it mentions that MLE for any model follows normal asymptotically. So thanks again.

Comment: Also, I found online that there are some other ways of estimating coefficients in logistic regression. Does any such (accepted) method have a sampling distribution?

Comment: Your extra question is difficult without links/references--- but you can ask it as a new question, with those links

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bias of maximum likelihood estimators for logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60723/bias-of-maximum-likelihood-estimators-for-logistic-regression)